# how to merge two different geometry and different material merge into one in three.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I draw one `square 2D line diagram` than square diagram into another `sample image` put in center position. but one is visible another hide. I used two different geometry, material. `one is line base material set a color`,`second image material`. I did marge but not properly. please, anyone, give the idea or what mistake in my code?

```
 var combined = new THREE.Geometry(); 

var squareGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
squareGeometry.vertices.push(
            new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(endX, startY, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(endX, endY, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(startX, endY, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0)
);
var squareMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: color});
var square = new THREE.Line(squareGeometry, squareMaterial);

var iconGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(objSize.width/2, objSize.height/2);
var iconMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/plantIcon.png')
});
var icon = new THREE.Mesh(iconGeometry,iconMaterial);


//      square.holes.push( icon);
//      THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(square, icon);

combined.merge(square.geometry, square.matrix);
combined.merge(icon.geometry, icon.matrix);

var merge = new THREE.Mesh(combined,new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/plantIcon.png'),//color: color
}));

merge.position.x = objPosition.x;
merge.position.y = objPosition.z;

scene.add(merge);
```

Comment: Do you try to combine `THREE.Line()` and `THREE.Mesh()`??

Comment: yes, I did try to combine the square=THREE.Line() and icon=THREE.Mesh. I expect one square diagram put into sample image. not working my code properly. what mistake?@prisoner849

Comment: They are of different types.

Answer (score 0):

I used `2 different Mesh`. one is `THREE.Line()` Mesh and second is `THREE.Mesh`. I did merge the grouping `var group = new THREE.Object3D()` method. Below my code. It's working.

```
var group = new THREE.Object3D();
var squareGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
squareGeometry.vertices.push(
                new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(endX, startY, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(endX, endY, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(startX, endY, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0)
);
var squareMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: color});
var square = new THREE.Line(squareGeometry, squareMaterial);

var iconGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry((objSize.width/2), (objSize.depth/2));
var iconMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/plantIcon.png')
         });
var icon = new THREE.Mesh(iconGeometry,iconMaterial);
icon.position.x = objPosition.x;
icon.position.y = objPosition.z;

group.add(square);
group.add(icon);

scene.add(group);
```